# Sending parameters to .net via angular in post method

Tags: angular

I am trying to send some parameters to the .net side but they say it is undefined.
they main problem is that i have two post method with same parameters so i am trying to send some string with the other on but that string is not going.

Angular side:

```
onSave(disData:PostModel,Mode) {
    var disupdateData=disData;

      //return this.http.post('http://localhost:60012/api/newdr/AddOrder', objJson);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: 'http://localhost:60042/api/newdr/AddOrder',               
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        data: disData,
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log("Inside the error method");
          return false;
        },
        success: function (data) {
          return true;

        }
    });
  }
    onApprove(disData:ApproveModel,strp1,strp2) {
      var disupdateData=disData;

        //return this.http.post('http://localhost:60012/api/newdr/AddOrder', objJson);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          async: true,
          url: 'http://localhost:60042/api/newdr/UpdateSummary',               
          dataType: "json",
          traditional: true,
          data:{ disData: disData, strp1: 'manish',strp2: 'goyal' },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
              console.log("Inside the error method");
            return false;
          },
          success: function (data) {
            return true;

          }
      });
```

Api Side:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public bool UpdateSummary(DiscountData disData, string strp1, string strp2)
        {

            CrudDataService objCrd = new CrudDataService();
            objCrd.UpdateSummary1(disData);
            return true;
        }
        [HttpPost] 
        public bool AddOrder(DiscountData disData)
        {

            CrudDataService objCrd = new CrudDataService();
            objCrd.InsertDiscountData(disData);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Which angular version do you use?

Comment: latest one angular 8

Comment: Why using ajax ?! Please take a look at [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Answer (score 1):

You must not use Ajax or JQuery, you should have an api service in your angular project, where you can communicate with you back end.

Regarding your question, use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http).

```
return new HttpClient().post('http://localhost:60012/api/newdr/AddOrde',objJson).pipe(
  map(anything=>{
    //todo return
  })
);
```

Something like that is how it should look like.
If the problem is building a JSon to send, use JSON.stringify(obj)

Comment: i am using a service for doing all this and am sending all the data, the right way. i didn't get what you are trying to say if you are not talking about this.